# Use Pdftron library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdftron, pdfnet

I trying to use Pdftron api in my python project but I can't add library in the project.
I read all document in pdftron site for python in the end I can't.
please help.

Comment: Look here https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/linux/get-started/python3/

Comment: A lot more information is required to answer your question, including; full error messages, python version you are targeting, logs from cmake/swig/pyhton, os details.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have to build your own Python3 bindings. Following this guide, it typically takes ~15 minutes to generate your bindings.
https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers#linux

Once created, you can look at our any of our Python samples to see how to load PDFNet.
https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers/tree/master/Samples/AddImageTest/PYTHON
https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers/blob/master/Samples/AddImageTest/PYTHON/RunTest.sh
https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers/blob/master/Samples/AddImageTest/PYTHON/AddImageTest.py

Comment: any ideas on how to make it using python3 in the Build step? It keeps using python2 in the Build step so I cannot run my python script

Comment: @Forrest I suspect your "python-dev" is 2.x, you would need to install 3.x version of python-dev. Also, make sure your runtime is 3.x.